# ¿Como puedo volver a recargar todos los controller con Angular?

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Hola estoy haciendo una app con Ionic1 y Angular1 y quiero que al salir sesión me recargue de nuevo todos los controllers.
Gracias.

```
    angular
    .module('starter')
    .controller('ProfilCtrl', ProfilCtrl);
       function ProfilCtrl($scope){
       var auth = uid;
       $scope.logout = function(){
        $state.go('welcome');
       }
    }
```

Comment: Como que se recarguen? A que te refieres con eso?

Comment: Cuando entro por primera vez a ProfilCtrl obtengo el uid de la sesión del usuario activo, pero si el usuario cierra sesión y vuelve a entrar con otro uid obtiene el uid de la session anterior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A raiz de tu comentario, no es necesario recargar los controladores si no, mas bien limpiar o borrar el valor del `uid` una vez que cierre sesion.

```
$scope.cerrarSession = function(){
    uid = "";
}
```

Dependiendo de tu estructura, si pones mas detalles de como generas ese `uid` , como usted cierra la session.

Comment: ya pero necesitaria el nuevo uid y ese se carga cuando entras por primera vez en el ProfileCtrl y es por ello que queria saber como se hace para recargar de nuevo los Ctrl

Comment: @EricRetamero como generas el uid y como lo obtienes desde otros controladores?

Comment: gracias a tu contestación me hizo reflexionar y encontré la solución.